# Recursive function for array integers

Tags: c, recursion

I have a function that takes an array `a[]` and its length `n`. I must calculate the sum of the numbers inside the array. I wrote this recursive function:

```
int somma(int a[], int n)
{
 if (n == 0) { return 0; }
 else {return a[n] + somma(a, n-1);}    
}
```

And I call it in my `main()` in this way:

```
int main() {   

 int array[5], ris;

 printf("Type the numbers of the array: \n");

 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
 { 
   scanf("%d", &array[i]); 
 }

 printf("\nThe sum is: %d.", somma(array,4));

 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

If the array contains `array = [2; 4; 7; 5]` the printf must show 18 (2+4+7+5). By the way the function returns me 88, can you help me?

I am using wxDevC++.

Comment: Don't forget that `a[0]` is also an element of the array, which `somma` skips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only reading the first four values in the array. `array[4]` contains garbage value

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) //change to 5
{ 
     scanf("%d", &array[i]); 
}
```

Your `somma` function is also wrong. It will always add `0` for `arr[0]`.

```
 if (n == -1) { return 0; } //change to this
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:-

```
for(int i=0; i<=4; i++)
 { 
   scanf("%d", &array[i]); 
 }
```

Also correct your somma

```
 if (n == -1) 
 { 
    return 0; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If an array has `n` elements, then the last element has index `n-1`. Correct your `somma` function like this:

```
int somma(int a[], int n) {
    if (n <= 0) { 
        return 0;
    }

    return a[n-1] + somma(a, n-1);    
}
```

Additionally, there are two (minor) issues with your code:

1. Variable declaration inside `for` head in `for(int i=0; i<4; i++)` is not allowed by C89, only C99 and C++. Probably DevC++ compiles it because the file is treated as C++, but you should know that it won't compile on GCC, unless you use the `-std=c99` switch.
2. `getch` is Windows-specific. On POSIX systems, use `getchar` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have updated the exit condition for recursion.

Comment: Note that the `<=` it's not strictly necessary (`==` would be ok), but it will avoid an infinite recursion in case of negative `n`.